# WSO2 type of response and api consumption

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new to WSO2 and I have some questions.

- I have an api and when consumption returns an XML response, I need it in JSON, from what I have read I must modify the "Response content type" but I don't know how
- Where can I find documentation to call the token generator api and my api through postman.
- Finally, some documentation of how the APIs are consumed from my final application

thank you very much

Comment: What is the API Manager version that you are using?

Comment: Follow this first. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/getting-started/quick-start-guide/

Comment: @Menaka API Manager 3.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an api and when consumption returns an XML response, I need it in JSON, from what I have read I must modify the "Response content type" but I don't know how

You have to set the messageType as application/json in the out sequence.

`<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>`

You can refer this for more details https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Working+with+JSON+Message+Payloads

And also please check this https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions to know how to add mediation extension for as out sequence in API manager

> Where can I find documentation to call the token generator api and my api through postman.
>   Refer this https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/oauth2/grant-types/overview/
>   Select your grant type and analyse it.
>
> Finally, some documentation of how the APIs are consumed from my final application
>   This may help you https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/consume-api/manage-subscription/subscribe-to-an-api/

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and sorry for the delay. See the "property name ..." where is it added? the documentation is from Wso2 EI and I am using AM, I have tried adding it in the api definition but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You have to add it as our -sequence and please refer this https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+Mediation+Extensions for that.